# Spotify API| DefaultDispatcher-worker-1

Tags: kotlin, spotify

I am using Spotify's API in my app to get the music history and stuff.
The problem is that, when I log in with some account which is not a developer account, it throws this error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Process: com.spotifylogin, PID: 22147
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.spotify.com/v1/me
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:255)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
at com.example.desgin_project.MainActivity$fetchSpotifyUserProfile$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:142)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: \[StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@56a358e, Dispatchers.Default\].
```

Then I made a developer account of that user account. It stills show this error while logging in. On the other hand, I use my another account, for creating the app, it works fine with it. It also has a developer account. I don't understand what the problem is. If I publish my app then, it would never take any simpler Spotify account?

```kotlin
val api = RetrofitBuilder.retrofitInstance!!.create(Interface::class.java)

val token = MyApp.shared?.getString(AppConstants.TOKEN)
Log.d("Token", "Token display: $token")
val call = api.getData("Bearer $token")
call.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<ArtistResponse> {
    @SuppressLint("SuspiciousIndentation")
    override fun onResponse(
        call: retrofit2.Call<ArtistResponse>,
        response: retrofit2.Response<ArtistResponse>,
    ) {
        if (response.isSuccessful){ }else{
            when (response.code()) { 403 ->{
                Log.d("Login Error ", "Server error.")
                showToast("Could not sync with spotify, Try again ")
            }}
```

It hits the 403 code when the error occurs.